# Rails 3: Swap a layout image for a flash animation

Tags: flash, image, ruby-on-rails-3, swap

So I have a helper that I'm using to swap my header image for another image that seems to work fine. This is my helper.

```
def header_image_tag
  @header_image ||= 'headers/image.png'
  image_tag @header_image
end

def header_image(image_path)
  @header_image = image_path
end
```

And in my View I use.

```
<% header_image('headers/newimage.png') %>
```

Now here is the tricky part, what I'd like to do, is instead of replacing it with a picture I'd like to swap in a flash banner.

I tried to do it by swapping in code instead using sanitize (which works just not using object tags). Below is first my helper for this...

```
def text_banner_tag
  @text_banner ||= 'textBanner.png'
  if @text_banner != "textBanner.png"
  else
    image_tag @text_banner
  end
end

def text_banner(object_code)
  @text_banner = object_code
end
```

and the code in my view...

```
<% text_banner(sanitize('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="970" height="48" id="FlashID" title="textbanner" alt="text banner">
      <param name="movie" value="/flash/textbanner.swf">
      <param name="quality" value="high">
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
      <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
      <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/flash/textbanner.swf" width="970" height="48">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
        <param name="expressinstall" value="/Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
        <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
        <div>
          <%= image_tag("textBanner.png", :size => "970x48", :alt => "text banner", :border => "0") %>
        </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
      </object>
      <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>')) %>
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest moving the entire `<object>` part into a partial (you could call it "_swf.html.erb") and making it work for just one swf.  Then, when everything works and the swf plays correctly, add parameters to it as needed.  Finally, whenever you need an swf object, use `render :partial => 'swf'` and parameterize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doing some digging around, for those that might come across this in the future and want to implement it on their own site, this is what I found and works great.

Basically you need to ad a set of tags and a set of attributes to the sanitize as sanitize only uses basic html its missing things like  which are much needed elements for flash.

Here's what I did in the helper:

```
  def text_banner_tag
    @text_banner ||= '<img src="/images/textBanner.png">'
      tags = %w(a acronym b strong i img em li ul ol h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 object param div blockquote br cite sub sup ins p)
      sanitize(@text_banner, :tags => tags, :attributes => %w(href classid title width height id alt data name value src))
  end

  def text_banner(object_code)
    @text_banner = object_code
  end
```

In the layout you call the banner using:

```
<%= text_banner_tag %>
```

And in the view that you'd like to display the flash banner for you add this to the top of the view:

```
<% text_banner('<object> <param> <div>text for no flash</div> </object>') %>
```

be sure to fill in everything you need for the flash object.

You can also use this to implement lots of other extras

**Security Warning** just be careful if your handing this usage out to users that are filling in forms that allow for code.